# Floating elements need to be centered within a table-cell li

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, floating, display

This one has driven me crazy - I can only find partial answers that won't work within the entirety of my code.  I'm trying to center an inline list of mixed 'like buttons' (pieces of `<script>` from external sites) and images (which I've set up as `<a>`s where 'like buttons' are not available)

The requirements are:
1. Everything needs to be aligned to the top edge of the parent div - which is why I've used ul, li, display:table and display:table-cell to align to top (and not just inline-block)
2. Everything needs to be on the same horizontal line, which is why they need to be floated (in the absence of inline-block)
3. Everything needs to be centred (this is the bit I can't achieve!)

This is my first time using the forum, and I'm not really a web-designer so please be gentle!  I've attached what code I think is relevant and helpful.

```css
#contact {
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#contactinfo {
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #00CCFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#share {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 1em;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul.button {
  display: table;
  min-height: 2em;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
ul.button li {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
img.sharebutton {
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
  <div id="contactinfo">
    <h2>
email <a href="mailto:info@lysamorrison.com"> info@lysamorrison.com</a><br>
call 0796 99 777 68
</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="share">
    <div class="sharebuttons">
      <ul class="button">
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.eventbrite.com/o/lma-training-amp-consultancy-8057832740" target="_blank">
            <img src="eventbrite.png" class="sharebutton" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sharebuttons">
      <ul class="button">
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.meetup.com/LMA-Personal-Professional-Development-Whitley-Bay-Meetup/#upcoming" target="_blank">
            <img src="meetup.png" class="sharebutton" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sharebuttons">
      <ul class="button">
        <li>
          <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
            lang: en_US
          </script>
          <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="1586406"></script>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sharebuttons">
      <ul class="button">
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/LMAtrainconsult" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @LMAtrainconsult</a> 
          <script>
            ! function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
              if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
              }
            }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
          </script>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sharebuttons">
      <ul class="button">
        <li>
          <div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/lmatrainingandconsultancy" data-height="35" data-layout="button" data-show-faces="true"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End of share div-->
</div>
```

Comment: An image of what this is supposed to look like would be useful. It's not really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Paulie - took some screen shots to show you but can't work out how to attach the pics.  Basically, I have a fairly fluid CSS layout that switches to another stylesheet depending on device, browser width etc.  At full width, the buttons align correctly to the right; when the width reduces below a certain no. of pixels, I want them centered instead - but can't make them BOTH align top and centered, using the float

Comment: You have to have the images on an image hosting site and provide links.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is the solution here; using 3 specific properties to address your needs.

1. Setting
   [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)
   to `flex-start` keeps the children vertically aligned to the top of
   their parent.
2. Setting
   [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)
   to `nowrap` (the default value) ensures the children stay on one
   line.
3. Setting
   [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)
   to `center` centres the children horizontally within the parent

Here's a simplified example:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:middle;}
ul{
    background:black;
    align-items:flex-start;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    justify-content:center;
    list-style:none;
    padding:2px;
}
li{
    margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img height="80" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/abstract/1/" width="100"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img height="50" src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/2/" width="75"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img height="150" src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/3/" width="200"></a></li>
</ul>
```